# read that time point of a video

Tags: pronunciation

[Should I use present continuous or present simple tense here to describe an action in a video?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249484/115654) says

> At **1:19**, he's holding the ball, and then drop it freely down to his foot

Should I read that time point like this?

> one minute and nineteen seconds of the video

or

> first minute and nineteenth second of the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd read it as "at one-nineteen he's ..." In context I'd understand this to mean "at video time one minute and nineteen seconds" (and not, for example "nineteen minutes past one in the afternoon")

The context (talking about youtube videos) makes "one-nineteen" quite clear.